# Approximating the identity function by a sequence of smooth functions satisfying some properties

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation-theory

I am reading a paper that claims the following without proof:

> Let $\mathbf{1}$ denote the identity function on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Then there exists a sequence of $C^{\infty}_c$ functions $\varphi_n =(\varphi^{(1)}_n , \varphi^{(2)}_n , \ldots, \varphi^{(d)}_n )  : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that on compact sets, 
>   $$
> \left\{
>                 \begin{array}{ll}
>                   \varphi_n \to \mathbf{1}, \\
>                   \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \varphi^{(i)}_n \to \delta_{i,j}, \quad \quad i,j \in \{1, \ldots, d\},\\
>                   \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \varphi^{(k)} _n          \to 0,    \quad \quad i,j,k \in \{1, \ldots, d\},   \end{array}
>               \right.
> $$
>   uniformly.

Strangely, it further claims that the choice of $\varphi_n$ can be made such that the following conditions are also satisfied:

> Without loss of generality, we can assume that there exists a constant $C$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
>   $$
> \left\{
>                 \begin{array}{ll}
>                   \| \varphi_n (v) \| \leq C \| v \|, \\
>                   \big| \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \varphi^{(i)}_n (v) \big|  \leq C, \quad \quad i,j \in \{1, \ldots, d\},\\
>                   \big| \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \varphi^{(k)} _n \big| \leq C,     \quad \quad i,j,k \in \{1, \ldots, d\},   \end{array}
>               \right.
> $$
>   and that $\varphi_n(v) =v$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|v \| \leq n$.

The only relevant result that I can recall is the fact that the set $C^{\infty}_c$ is dense in $L^p$. However, this doesn't give any information about the derivatives of $\varphi_n$, nor boundedness of the derivatives.  Does this involve any theorem in Sobolev spaces? I have absolutely no idea at the moment.

Comment: Do you know how functions can be approximated by convolution with a mollifier?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, but I don't know what mollifiers to use... The fact that the uniform convergence holds for ANY compact set also bothers me.

Comment: What does $\varphi^{(i)}_n \to \bf 1$ mean when $\varphi^{(i)}_n : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ but $\bf 1 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Assuming it's meant to be $\varphi_n \to {\rm id}_{\mathbb R^d}$ (which is what the derivative $\delta_{ij}$ seems to suggest), you should be able to achieve this by multiplying ${\rm id}$ by a suitably scaled radial bump function that's identically $1$ for $r < 2n$ and $0$ for $r > 3n$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes, you are right. I've confused the notations a bit. I've now edited the question. I still don't understand how we can show this convergence for any compact set. (I assume this is what " on compact sets" means.) This is super strange, since at any point $0 \neq x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the sequence $\varphi_n (x)$ is non-zero for large values of $n$. This seems to contradict the requirement that $\varphi_n \in C^{\infty}_c$.....

Comment: $\varphi_n \in C^\infty_c$ doesn't mean each element of the sequence has to have the *same* compact support - indeed, the requirements in your second yellow box guarantee the supports will grow arbitrarily large as $n \to \infty$. The convergence on compact sets is super easy if you use my suggestion - any compact set is contained in some ball $B_{2N}$, and once $n > N$ the sequence is constant on that ball.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Can the convolution with bump functions guarantee the conditions for the first and second order derivatives?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis If I understand it correctly by treating "on compact sets" to mean "any compact set", then basically, the three convergence statements in the first yellow box hold pointwise over the entire $\mathbb{R}^d$, which seems very strange to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56212/discussion-between-anthony-carapetis-and-richard).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Is the convolution of $I_d$ with the bump function that you suggested in $C^{\infty}_c$?

Comment: @Richard Read what I wrote in the chat linked above. You want to multiply, not convolve - convolution can improve regularity but not shrink support. In this case the function is already super regular, the problem is the support.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis OK. So $\varphi_n$ is just the sequence of bump functions that you suggested? Since the product of the identity function with any function is that function itself...

Comment: The identity function is ${\bf 1}(x) = x$, not ${\bf 1}(x) = 1$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Oh yeah, you're right. I got confused with the composition. I think I understand now. Thanks.